# Cannot Preload Font in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

I spent a couple of hours and could not find any solution for this. I am trying to preload Elegant Icons font with .woff extension and I think i am doing everything correctly, however, Google Page Speed Insights still finding issues:

> "We recommend that you use `<link rel = preload>` to specify earlier
> retrieval of resources".

I can see that the icons from the font get loaded on the frontend, however, according to Google Page Speed Insights, the font is still not preloaded. Any help will be much appreaciated. Here is my code in functions.php:

```
function my_fonts() {
    //Add Elegant Icons font
    wp_enqueue_style( 'elegant-icons-font', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/font/ElegantIcons.woff' );
    
        //Add Elegant Icons css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'elegant-icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/elegantIcons.css' );
}


add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_fonts' );


/* Preload Icons font */

function my_font_loader_tag_filter($html, $handle) {

  if($handle === 'elegant-icons-font' ) {

return str_replace("rel='stylesheet'", "rel='preload' as='font' type='font/woff2' crossorigin='anonymous'", $html);

  }
  
  return $html;

}

add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'my_font_loader_tag_filter',10, 2);
```

In Elegant Icons css i have

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
    src: url('../fonts/ElegantIcons.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/ElegantIcons.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

If i remove the `src` property from the css file, the icons do not display on the frontend anymore. I even tried hardcoding the link with preload attribute in the site header but Google Page Speed insights is still not happy. I really ran out of any ideas.

Comment: `function font_preload() {
    echo '<link rel="preload" href="/assets/font/ElegantIcons.woff" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">
}
add_action('wp_head', 'font_preload', 0);` could work for you, a lot simpler if not a little hacky using `echo`. I am sure someone with better WordPress knowledge will tidy that up and return it properly though, I haven't used it in a while!

Comment: @Badan, has the above comment helped? I think it is the correct answer. FYI a preload link is something different then a normal enqueued style and should be both present in the head.